# Delete Wordpress media in database after FTP delete

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

Through the FTP I've deleted my 2020 uploads folder and several subfolders of the 2021 folder. This because the Media library contained 250.000 images. The only problem is that those images still exist in the database.

I've got this link that explains how to delete those rows: https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/wordpress-media-library-database-rows-and-tables

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment";
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "_wp_attached_file";
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "_wp_attachment_metadata";
```

But I don't want to delete all rows, but within a certain date range. Is this the correct addition to the query?

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment" AND DateField BETWEEN "01/01/2020" to "01/08/2021";
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "_wp_attached_file" AND DateField BETWEEN "01/01/2020" to "01/08/2021";
DELETE FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "_wp_attachment_metadata" AND DateField BETWEEN "01/01/2020" to "01/08/2021";
```

Comment: is there a datefield?  and the line must be `AND DateField BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and '2021-08-1';`

Comment: When I run the query without date range I see the column 'post_date'. I changed the query to: 

`SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = "attachment" AND `post_date` BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-08-01 00:00:00';
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "_wp_attached_file" AND `post_date` BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-08-01 00:00:00';
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = "_wp_attachment_metadata" `post_date` BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and '2021-08-01 00:00:00';`

But I get this error back: #1054 - Unknown column 'post_date' in where clause

Comment: that is what i asked, i don't remember seen a column of that name, so you nee to find it and join the table or tablse with that information

Comment: But the column post_date is there.

Comment: if mysql tells you that it can't find it it is true. Make abackup of your server, copy the data and test your query.